# Spring Boot "ErrorPageFilter" creates random overflow and high CPU

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jetty

I'm using Spring Boot 1.1.0 and Jetty 9.1.1.
I observed that sometimes, one of the mvc threads are on 100% CPU constantly.
After using jstack and getting a stack dump of the problem, I've found this:

... more repeated stack omitted ...

```
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher$ForwardAttributes.setAttribute(Dispatcher.java:404)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher$ForwardAttributes.setAttribute(Dispatcher.java:404)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher$ForwardAttributes.setAttribute(Dispatcher.java:404)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher$ForwardAttributes.setAttribute(Dispatcher.java:404)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher$ForwardAttributes.setAttribute(Dispatcher.java:404)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher$ForwardAttributes.setAttribute(Dispatcher.java:404)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher$ForwardAttributes.setAttribute(Dispatcher.java:404)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher$ForwardAttributes.setAttribute(Dispatcher.java:404)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher$ForwardAttributes.setAttribute(Dispatcher.java:404)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher$ForwardAttributes.setAttribute(Dispatcher.java:404)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher$ForwardAttributes.setAttribute(Dispatcher.java:404)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher$ForwardAttributes.setAttribute(Dispatcher.java:404)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher$ForwardAttributes.setAttribute(Dispatcher.java:404)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.setAttribute(Request.java:1695)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.setErrorAttributes(ErrorPageFilter.java:164)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.handleErrorStatus(ErrorPageFilter.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:85)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1615)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:550)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:586)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1112)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:479)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1046)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:261)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:101)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.handleErrorStatus(ErrorPageFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:85)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1615)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:550)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:586)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1112)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:479)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1046)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:261)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:101)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.handleErrorStatus(ErrorPageFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:85)
```

... more repeated stack omitted ...

this is never-ending loop which causes the thread to stop responding.
I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Could you please help how to debug and solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Set your debugger breakpoint on Dispatcher.java line 404 and see what's happening.

Comment: Hi David, This behavior happens randomly on production which I cannot reproduce at all. I traced that bug to a Jetty 9.1.1 implementation of Servlet 2.5 API. A simple if condition on ForwardAttributes could've solved it. But something that spring boot does triggers it (I'm guessing ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver) As said I cannot reproduce this so i'm asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read, Spring Boot doesn't officially support Servlet 2.5.  Apparently there's ways to get it working.  If you look at Dave Syer's response to SO question here [How to deploy Spring Boot app to Tomcat 6 Servlet 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24435718/how-to-deploy-spring-boot-app-to-tomcat-6-servlet-2-5#24435852) that might help.  Not sure if upgrading to Spring Boot 1.1.4 would help you any.

Comment: That was my mistake, I was thinking about version 3 but got confused while reading some possible solutions. Anyways I'm using 3.1. Sorry for confusion